# Timeout when sending email using nodemailer behind a corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, nodemailer

I am sending email behind a proxy using nodemailer.

The code works when sending when I am not behind a proxy.

But I get this error when behind a proxy ...

Error connect ETIMEDOUT

My transport config code looks like this ...

```
this.transporter =      
nodemailer.createTransport(config.providers.sparkPost.transport, {
  requireTLS: true,
  proxy: HTTP_PROXY_AND_PORT_HERE
})
```

Any ideas? Thx

NOTE: It says ..

The proxy must allow CONNECT tunnels to SMTP ports - Not sure what this means and not sure that the proxy I am behind does allow this - Any way of finding out? Could I use a socks5 proxy? Again how do I find out?

More questions than answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by doing the work in an environment that is not behind a proxy!